# What is the subject of the sentence "Go home now"?

Tags: subjects, parsing, imperative-sentences

Go home now!

- home
- go
- you

While 'you' isn't in the sentence, it was picked as the subject. Is 'you' the correct answer?

Comment: This is what's sometimes known as an "implied you".

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/a/124251/216106

Answer (score 1):

In English, imperative sentences don't have an explicit subject.  In fact, you can recognise an imperative by the base form of a verb used without a subject.

The implied subject is always the person being spoken to, and so is "you".

Even in sentences like "Peter, go home now!"  the word "Peter" is an interjection or vocative. Its purpose is to attract someone's attention, rather than take part in the syntax. The subject is still implied as "you", but we can infer that the name of "you" is Peter.

Answer (score 0):

In the sentence 'Go Home now!', the subject 'you' is hidden.

Comment: Can you expand to tell the questioner why that is?